# Usando un trigger insertar en una tabla valores obtenidos de otra tabla, despues de insertar un registro

Tags: mysql, trigger, insertar, consultar

Estoy tratando de crear un trigger que me permita después de insertar un registro en la tabla personal, insertar en otra tabla "cursos_personal", una serie de campos que dependerá de los elementos contenidos en otra tabla que se llama temas.

Entonces al momento de insertar una persona nueva en la tabla personal,  pretendo leer la tabla temas, y que me tome un valor de la tabla personal y 15 identificadores de temas y los inserte en cursos_personal,  estuve indagando y cree este trigger pero ni siquiera me deja guardarlo

```html
BEGIN
 
 SET @ID_ASOCIADO = NEW.id_asociado;
 

 INSERT INTO cursos_personal(id_asociado,id_tema)
 VALUES(@ID_ASOCIADO,@ID_TEMA)
 SELECT temas.id_tema
 FROM temas 
 GROUP BY temas.id_tema;
 
 SET @ID_TEMA = NEW.id_tema;

 
 
 END
```

Un compañero de trabajo me comento que se podía hacer una inserción masiva en la tabla cursos_personal, pero al parecer no me quedo claro su ejemplo o no le entendí. En base a su ejemplo fue que trate de hacer el trigger pero no he logrado nada.

Comment: Ayúdanos a ayudarte y pásanos las tablas en SQL con algún dato de muestra y un ejemplo de lo que te gustaría que apareciera en `cursos_personal` para una nueva inserción. Lo que necesitas está perfectamente explicado, ahora necesitamos datos concretos :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que presentas ciertos errores en la sintaxis al momento de hacer una inserción por medio de un `select`. Basciamente para poder insertar por medio de un select tienes que hacer que coincidan las columnas del `select` con las columnas del `insert`, por lo que tu consulta quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
INSERT INTO cursos_personal(id_asociado,id_tema)
SELECT @ID_ASOCIADO AS id_asociado, temas.id_tema
FROM temas 
GROUP BY temas.id_tema;
```

Ahora, solucionado eso, es necesario dar las instrucciones del `trigger`, para poder especificar en qué momento de ejecutará. En tu caso, como mencionas que es despues de insertar la intrucción sería:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `crear_temas_personal` AFTER INSERT ON `personal`
```

Donde `AFTER INSERT` indica que será depues de la inserción en (`ON`) la tabla personal.

Teniendo estos dos conceptos, para crear tu `trigger` tendrías que ejecutar la siguiente instrucción

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `crear_temas_personal` AFTER INSERT ON `personal`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    
    SET @ID_ASOCIADO = NEW.id_asociado;
 
    INSERT INTO cursos_personal(id_asociado,id_tema)
    SELECT @ID_ASOCIADO AS id_asociado, temas.id_tema
    FROM temas 
    GROUP BY temas.id_tema;

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Con esta consulta resolverías tu detalle.

Te recomiendo leer los [ejemplos de triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) que proporciona el sitio de MySql

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, si efectivamente fue un error de mi parte, a pesar de que me lo explico un compañero de trabajo, creo que no le entendi del todo en la forma que se tenia que escribir la consulta.  Hice una prueba rapida y aunque solo me cargo el id_asociado, el resto funciono tal cual lo requeria.  Te agradezo tu aporte.

Comment: @ Abraham Chan Ya cargaron la totalidad de los datos (1580 registros nuevos)  y se actualizo sin problema la tabla en base al trigger. Te agradezco la explicación. Saludos